# How to determine if a box2d body is touching the center of a sensor?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a sensor which applies forces to objects that move inside its bounds. I want to determine if a body is touching the centre of that sensor.

I can easily detect if an object is inside / touching the sensor or another body, but I'm not sure how to check if a body is in the centre of a given sensor.

Edit: The sensor is actually a vortex which I asked about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670991/459116). When objects are touching (or practically in, or on) the sensor it applies force toward it's own midpoint. When objects hit the midpoint I want them to do something, but I'm not sure how to check whether a given body is touching/inside the bounds of the sensor AND touching its midpoint.

In the (really well drawn) diagram below the blue circle is the sensor, the green circle is a body, and the little blue dot is the midpoint.

[image]

UPDATE: In the end I put a sensor in the middle and checked for that - it was the simplest way.

Comment: Smells like Skitch. Skitch is awesome. However, I think you should explain a bit better what your situation is. The "bounds"? Does that mean "touching the sensor"? Or are you checking manually the distance between the sensor and the object?

Comment: Skitch is awesome! Added more information that hopefully clarifies things.

Comment: Just put another sensor in the middle.

Comment: @iforce2d So I put a sensor in the middle. Simple. If you pop that as an answer I'll mark correct - thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

1. Convert the world position of the sensor to a local point of the body you want to test.
2. Loop through all fixtures of the body and check if the local point you converted is in the fixture.
3. If you found one, break. Otherwise it is not touching the center of the body.

I'm not good in Objective-C, so I will write in C++ a code example:

```
bool checkForTouchingCenter(b2Body *sensorBody, b2Body *bodyToTest)
{

    b2Vec2 sensorPosition = sensorBody->GetPosition();
    b2Vec2 localPosition = bodyToTest->GetLocalPoint(sensorPosition);

    // An AABB check would be nice here, unless you test only the bodies that
    // are already touching the sensor.

    for (b2Fixture *fixture = bodyToTest->GetFixtureList(); fixture != 0; fixture = fixture->GetNext())
    {
        if (fixture->TestPoint(localPosition))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Hint: Only test bodies that are already touching the sensor.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer. Are you sure you mean sensorBody->GetWorldPosition()? That's not a method of b2Body and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It looks like it makes sense, I think your logic is really good - but it just doesn't work.