# Box2d BlackHole attraction force

Tags: box2d, processing

I'm looking to add a blackhole feature on my game, but i'm stuck at the calcul of the attraction force.

I'm aware of [Make a Vortex in Box2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565637/make-a-vortex-in-box2d)

But actually my objects are not attracted by the blackhole, they are going away from the center little by little

Here is my code :

```
   public void applyVortexForce(PhysicBody bodyCollider) {

    Vec2 speed = this._physicBody.getBody()
            .getLinearVelocityFromWorldPoint(
                    bodyCollider.getBody().getWorldCenter());

    speed.mul(1.8f);
    Vec2 currentSpeed = new Vec2(bodyCollider.getBody()
            .getLinearVelocity().x, bodyCollider.getBody()
            .getLinearVelocity().y);

    Vec2 diff = speed.sub(currentSpeed);

    currentSpeed = currentSpeed.add(diff);
    currentSpeed.mul(bodyCollider.getBody().getMass());

    bodyCollider.getBody().setLinearVelocity(
            new Vec2(currentSpeed.x, currentSpeed.y));
}
```

Comment: So you want a reverse vortex?

Comment: I want objects going into the vortex, like a black hole, with my code its going outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest applying forces based on the distance between bodies and your 'vortex', instead of manually changing linear velocity.

[This tutorial](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/03/28/simulate-radial-gravity-also-know-as-planet-gravity-with-box2d-as-seen-on-angry-birds-space/) shows you how to simulate radial gravity, I think that could fit for your purpose

Comment: I've  combined both algorithm and its working well ! thanks a lot